# Android: Securing Your Private Key

Tags: android, security, signature

I have been Reading the "Securing Your Private Key" section on the Android website. It wanrs about the possibility of authoring identity being compromised.

Then, is it possible to access to the signature of a published app? I mean for example to extract the autor identity, or any kind of information just from an apk file? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can obtain the signature of installed apps. The example below will get all the signatures used to sign a package.

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pkgName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    Signature[] sigs = info.signatures;
    for (Signature sig : sigs) {
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(sig.toByteArray());
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
        // Verify or inspect cert here
    }
} catch (...) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without access to your private key.  That's why they suggest you secure it :)  You also *must* sign an app with the same key if you wish to update it in the future.  Lose your key = new app in the market and the new app will have to have a unique package name.

Comment: then, the less information a private key embeds the better, right? Why do we need to insert iformation such as organization, etc. if nobody can access to it... without access to the private key?

Comment: Incorrect.  You can obtain a signature without a private key.  The signature does not contain any secrets.

Answer (score 0):

They would only have access to your private key if you left it hanging around somewhere in the clear on a publicly viewable page/folder. That being said there is nothing preventing someone from unzipping your application making changes and then resigning it with another key and running it locally. For someone to inject malicious code into your app and update it on the Play Store they need multiple pieces of info. Not only do they need your key but they need your google developer account info.